# Retrieve data attributes from json in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a data attribute field formatted like a json array, like so:

```
<span data-suggest="{["name","legalname"],"type":"url",true}">action</span>
```

In Jquery, i want to retrieve the values of the first parameter, that is:

```
name, legalname
```

I've tried the following (with a couple of variants), with no success.

```
var suggest = $(this).data("suggest");
var elements = suggest[0];

elements.each(function() {
    alert('get values in first parameter');
});
```

Help!

Comment: `{["name","legalname"],"type":"url",true}` isn't a valid data structure. Objects **must** have a key / value.

Comment: The double quotes in your value are going to fubar your data-suggest value also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to parse the JSON like this..

```
var suggest = $(this).data("suggest");
var json = JSON.parse(suggest);
console.log(json);
```

And note that your JSON is not formatted correctly. here is proper example:

```
{"employees":[
{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
{"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```